# How do I get sonarqube to depend on jacocoTestReport?

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

Why doesn't this work and how can I get the result I'm looking for? Specifically, I want jacoco to run before sonarqube.

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'

    test {
        jacoco {
            excludes = [...,
                         "javolution.*"]
        }
    }

    jacocoTestReport {
        dependsOn tasks.withType(Test)//This makes integrationTests go. 
    }

//This is the part that I can't get to work:
project.tasks["sonarqube"].dependsOn jacocoTestReport
}
```

Error is:

```
* Where:
Build file '/dev/abc/build.gradle' line: 92

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'abc'.
> Task with name 'sonarqube' not found in project ':thingamajig'.
```

Of course `thingamajig` is an empty parent directory. No `build.gradle` there but it has many sub-directories that do have a `build.gradle`. I've tried a number of things like checking the task graph and catching an swallowing the Exception when calling `project.tasks.getByName()` Time to punt, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subprojects do not have an own sonar runner task. Make the root projects sonar runner task depend on the subprojects jacocoTestReport tasks.

In my `build.gradle` this looks like

```
if (hasProperty('sonarAnalyseOnly') && sonarAnalyseOnly.toBoolean()) {
   tasks.sonarRunner.dependsOn = []
} else {
   tasks.sonarRunner.dependsOn {
      project.subprojects.findAll { !it.sonarRunner.skipProject }.collect {
         [
               it.tasks.compileSharedJava,
               it.tasks.compileServerJava,
               it.tasks.compileGuiJava,
               it.tasks.integTest,
               it.tasks.jacocoMerge
         ]
      }.flatten()
   }
}
```

Comment: Same error, I'm afraid. I added subproject -> and used subproject.tasks["sonarqube"].dependsOn jacocoTestReport

Comment: I added println subProject.name and it prints pretty much what I would expect. The name of the subproject.

Comment: Reminder: thingamajig is completely empty. There's not even a build.gradle file in there but it's still being found and failed on.

Comment: rootProject.tasks["sonarqube"].dependsOn jacocoTestReport seems to work at least partially. Still looking at it tho. I think maybe sonarqube task is only added to root by design. I note that you can't access it in subprojects.

Comment: Ah right, forgot that and misread, sorry. You are right. The sonarqube task is only available on the project where you applied the plugin and also should only be there.

Comment: "at least" partially, it was still running. ;-) It seems to work fine.

Comment: I don't think I have a sonarRunner. I'm using the org.sonarqube plugin.

Comment: I have an older version of it. I guess they renamed the task, to conform to the software renaming

Comment: Add some context regarding "sonarAnalyseOnly" (what is it?) and I will accept.

Comment: Just a project property that I invented, to just start the analysis without compiling first. Instead the class files of the last compilation are used. I happened to need this from time to time.

Answer (score 4):

It has been a few years since the Accepted answer was posted. This question has become relevant once again since SonarQube removed its automatic dependency on the `test` task.

For SonarQube plugin version `3.4.0.2513` and Gradle versison `6.9.1`, this is what worked for me:

```
def LinkedHashSet jacocoSet = new LinkedHashSet()
subprojects {
    jacocoSet.addAll(
        tasks.findAll({ it.name.contains('jacocoTestReport') || it.name == 'test' })
    )
    // println tasks.findAll {it.name.contains('sonar')}  //returns: []
}
rootProject.tasks.sonarqube.dependsOn = jacocoSet
```

Differences from the Accepted answer:

- `sonarRunner` was not a valid task, neither in the `rootProject` nor in the `subproject`s.
- `project.subprojects` is a list of subprojects, not tasks. So, you need to access the subprojects' tasks list before you can run the task filter so that you can add a task object (instead of a project object) to `dependsOn`.